# Why doesn't FindInstance work with inequalities?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to use FindInstance to find some simple counterexamples to the equality `a^(1/n)+b^(1/n)=((a+b)^((1/n)))` , with a, b and n integers. (Ex: a -> 9, b -> 16, n -> 2)

However the simplest formulation went into an infinite loop :

```
In:= FindInstance[(a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) != (a + b)^(1/n) ), {n, a, b},Integers]
Out= $Aborted
```

This doesn't happen if the domain is real, but the instances are (unnecessarily?) huge fractions.

```
In:= FindInstance[a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) != (a + b)^(1/n), {n, a, b}, Reals]

Out= {{n -> -(9143147128/5748624679), a -> 15296522407/8870661169, 
  b -> 37594049291/24286235770}}
```

A partial result is obtained by breaking down the question:

```
In:= FindInstance[a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) > (a + b)^(1/n), {n, a, b}, Integers]

Out= {{n -> 1117, a -> 133, b -> 588}}
```

Even if:

```
In:= FindInstance[a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) < (a + b)^(1/n), {n, a, b}, Integers]
```

Generates this message:

```
FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist.
```

Combining the two inequalities is ok:

```
In:= FindInstance[
 a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) > (a + b)^(1/n) || a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) < (a + b)^(1/n), {n, 
  a, b}, Integers]

Out= {{n -> 1117, a -> 133, b -> 588}}
```

However, I get an "error" if I specify the number of instances to find:

```
In:= FindInstance[
 a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) > (a + b)^(1/n) || a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) < (a + b)^(1/n), {n, 
  a, b}, Integers, 2]
FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist.
```

**There are three questions I can' t answer :**

1. why does inequality "crash the system" (I mean I have to "quit kernel" and restart it)?
2. why is it not possible to specify the number of instances?
3. how can you specify the range of the variables?(Below are two failed attempts .)

   ```
   In:= Assuming[n < 10 && a <= 100 && b <= 100, 
            FindInstance[a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) > (a + b)^(1/n) || a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) < (a + b)^(1/n), {n, a, b}, Integers]]

   Out= {{n -> 1117, a -> 133, b -> 588}}

   In:= Assuming[n < 10 && a < 10 && b < 10, 
       FindInstance[(a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) > (a + b)^(1/n) || 
             a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) < (a + b)^(1/n) ) && (n < 10 && a < 10 && b < 10), {n, 
           a, b}, Integers]]

   Out= $Aborted
   ```

Comment: To quickly find 10 simple counterexamples `FindInstance[(a^(1/n)+b^(1/n)!=(a+b)^(1/n) )&&n==2,{n,a,b},Integers,10]` I don't think it "crashed the system. If MMA printed a system exception error message or closed the MMA session or reformatted your hard drive then that would qualify for "crashed the system." Instead the algorithm couldn't complete what you asked for. Perhaps because almost every a,b,n for n>1 satisfies your inequality. My example and the docs for `FindInstance` show using inequalities. Changing `n==2` to `n==2&&3<a<5` lets you specify the range of a Does this help?

Comment: @Bill By "crash" I mean that I have to locally terminate the kernel and restart it, otherwise the same formulas computed again give "error" or "insufficient methods".

Comment: If we all use the same definitions I think we will be more likely to get correct answers and solutions to problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Restrict the domain to `PositiveIntegers`

```
FindInstance[(a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) != (a + b)^(1/n)), {n, a, 
  b}, PositiveIntegers]

(* {{n -> 1117, a -> 133, b -> 588}} *)
```

or equivalently,

```
FindInstance[{(a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) != (a + b)^(1/n)), 
  Thread[{n, a, b} > 0]} // 
   Flatten, {n, a, b}, Integers]

(* {{n -> 1117, a -> 133, b -> 588}} *)
```

Requiring smaller values makes the problem simpler

```
FindInstance[{(a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) != (a + b)^(1/n)), 
  Thread[{n, a, b} < 10]} //
   Flatten, {n, a, b}, PositiveIntegers, 10]

(* {{n -> 9, a -> 9, b -> 3}, {n -> 8, a -> 5, b -> 8}, {n -> 3, a -> 6, 
  b -> 8}, {n -> 9, a -> 8, b -> 8}, {n -> 8, a -> 6, b -> 1}, {n -> 3, 
  a -> 1, b -> 8}, {n -> 6, a -> 8, b -> 3}, {n -> 8, a -> 5, 
  b -> 9}, {n -> 4, a -> 9, b -> 5}, {n -> 2, a -> 6, b -> 3}} *)
```

or

```
FindInstance[{(a^(1/n) + b^(1/n) != (a + b)^(1/n)), 
   Thread[0 < {n, a, b} < 10]} // Flatten, {n, a, b}, Integers, 10]

(* {{n -> 9, a -> 9, b -> 3}, {n -> 8, a -> 5, b -> 8}, {n -> 3, a -> 6, 
  b -> 8}, {n -> 9, a -> 8, b -> 8}, {n -> 8, a -> 6, b -> 1}, {n -> 3, 
  a -> 1, b -> 8}, {n -> 6, a -> 8, b -> 3}, {n -> 8, a -> 5, 
  b -> 9}, {n -> 4, a -> 9, b -> 5}, {n -> 2, a -> 6, b -> 3}} *)
```